# Why do I get the segmentation fault error (arrays as elements of classes)?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I have a class called *Item* that stores an array of a size known at compile time:

```
class Item
{
  int *data;
public:
  Item(int array[], int length)
  {
    std::copy(array, array + length, data); // Line A
  }
};
```

In my example the size equals to 1, but for my project I need greater values as well. Here is a class *Box* that stores two *Item*s. I don't want to have two arguments in the constructor, so I pass an array of size 2 (since the class can only store 2 *Item*s and each of them stores an array of length 1).

```
class Box
{
  Item *item1;
  Item *item2;
public:
  Box(int (&array)[2])
  {
    item1 = new Item(array, 1);
    item2 = new Item(array + 1, 1);
  }
  ~Box()
  {
    delete item1;
    delete item2;
  }
};
```

And this is how I create a pointer to a *Box* object:

```
int main()
{
  int tab[] = {8, 9};
  Box *box = new Box(tab);
  delete box;
  return 0;
}
```

After running the above piece of code, I got the following error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I debugged it and it turned out that the line A is causing the problem. I also create the Item class in my main function and it doesn't give me any errors.

It seems to me that I'm trying to access some memory outside of my table, but this can't be true - I just want to copy one element of my array. Besides, the c++ compiler wouldn't mind it anyway.

So, what am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I'm using the g++ compiler and the *-std=c++11* option.

I can use *std::array* instead, but I'd like to know what mistake am I making just out of curiosity.

Comment: You never initialize the pointer `data`?

Comment: You never allocate memory for `Item::data`, at least you don't show the code.

Comment: I do, I forgot to show it. It works now, but the original problem I had wasn't solved. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Why are you using all those pointers for? I really see no need for *any* of the pointers Use constructor initializer lists, `std::vector` and `std::array` and you can get rid of all those pointers and don't have to worry about problems like this (and more problems that you will have because your use of pointers).

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question.

Comment: Regarding the pointer issue, see e.g. [here for an example of your program without pointers](http://ideone.com/51zVOl), and without any crash. It can probably be more generic by having the `Box` constructor also take an iterator range.

Answer (score 3):

`Item` isn't quite right. When you have:

```
std::copy(array, array + length, data); // Line A
```

You're never actually allocating anything for `data` first - so you're writing into whatever garbage happens to be in that pointer when it's initialized. You need to first do something like:

```
data = new int[length];
std::copy(array, array + length, data);
```

Although then you have remember to add a destructor, and copy/move assignment. Even better would be to simply use what the standard provides:

```
using Item = std::vector<int>;
```

---

> Besides, the c++ compiler wouldn't mind it anyway.

Just because code *compiles* doesn't mean it works. Compilation catches a lot of bugs for us, but it can't do everything!

Answer (score 2):

The expression `new int(length)` only allocates a *single* `int` and initializes it to the value of `lenght`.

You need to use square brackets `[]` for the size: `new int[length]`.

Comment: I think this was OP miscopying my answer into the question - it wasn't originally there and I just rolled it back (sorry).